# AWS API Gateway integration request body mapping template throws out passed in values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm having a problem using AWS API Gateway where all of my combinations of inputs works, except for one where it throws out the other passed in values.

Here is my template...

```
#set($greet = $input.params('greet'))
#set($name = $input.params('username'))
{
#if($greet != "")
    "greet": "$greet"
    #if($name != "")
    ,
    #end
#end
#if($name != "")
    "name": "$name"
#end
}
```

And my url is `/user/{username}/say/{greet}`

When I test the endpoint and send in no greeting or username, it works. When I send in a greeting, but no username, it works. When I send in both a greeting and username, it works. (By "works" I mean it passes along the values to my lambda function.)

But for some reason, when I send in a username, but no greeting, the mapping totally throws out the username and doesn't send it through (acts as if $name = ''). It still goes to the right endpoint because the right lambda function executes, the mapping just sends an empty object instead of an object with just the name property.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: If neither value is set, your JSON body seems like it will be invalid, containing `{ , }`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot if neither is set, the JSON body is valid because it will spit out only `{ }`. I have verified this works as expected. It's the case of giving a username, but no greeting that returns nothing for some reason.

Comment: You're right, I misread this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping is fine the way it is. I would guess that your API Gateway configuration needs to be adjusted for the scenario of an empty greeting.

If no greeting is present, AWS does not execute the method binding behind the variable, but the parent resource (in this case the '/say'-method binding). So you would need two method definitions, one with a greeting and one without. Both can be identically configured since your mapping template supports both outcomes.

[image: api resource structure]

Comment: Makes sense, but any idea why it's still going to the correct lambda function anyways? (without configuring /user/{username}/say)

Comment: It shouldn't, I tried your config and without the second method, my lambda wasn't called by the API Gateway.

Comment: Ah, I see. It calls it fine in the testing feature of Gateway, but not when it's deployed. I feel like it should fail in Gateway testing, but I guess it doesn't. Welp, I'll just chalk it up to weirdness.